# Jackson - treat empty collection as null during serialization to json

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose that I have the following POJO

```
public class Pojo {
   private Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When I do serialize it to the json, I've got the following output

```
{"stringSet":[]}
```

However, per requirements, I need the following:

```
{"stringSet":null}
```

I have tried to implement the custom `StdSerializer<Set>`

```
public class CustomStdSerializer extends StdSerializer<Set> {
    protected CustomStdSerializer() {
        super(Set.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Set set, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (set.size() == 0){
            jsonGenerator.writeNull();
        }

    }
}
```

But the output of it is the following

```
{"stringSet":}
```

How can I write null value in json?

Comment: Is that faulty json output only when you have a non-empty Set? I noticed your `serialize` function defines what to do if the set is empty, but not what to do if it's not.

Comment: No, this faulty json is being produced for empty set (size() == 0). For other cases it is perfectly valid.

Comment: I get `{"stringSet":null}` with your `Serializer` which version of jackson do you use? please also show your code that serialize your POJO

Comment: Cannot reproduce with jackson `2.6.6` and `2.8.5`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto did you initialize the set in the field declaration? If yes, then it might be the problem in my Jackson bean configuration. Will take look at my code and update my question.

Comment: yes, I simply added a getter and a setter for this field

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same requirement a while ago.

The reason why you get a [] stringSet  is because during declaration itself you are doing `new HashSet<>();`

and i am quite sure that in your setter method you might be simply doing

```
public void setStringSet(Set<String> stringSet){
   this.stringSet = stringSet;
}
```

instead you could do

```
public void setStringSet(Set<String> stringSet){
   if(stringSet.isEmpty()){
      this.stringSet.clear();
   } else{
      this.stringSet = stringSet;
   }
}
```

and this just worked fine for me.